# How to change Material-UI TextField InputAdornment background color?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

**First 10% one background color ,another 90% another background color.**

```
<TextField
  className={classes.root}                  
  type="text"
  placeholder="username"
  variant="outlined"
  style={{borderRadius:'50',
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }}
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <PersonIcon />
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>
```

I attach demo textfield in below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is how you override the `InputAdornment` to achieve the same effect in your screenshot. Note that the `input` next to the `InputAdornment` has its `box-sizing` set to `content-box`, so it's not as simple as setting the `height` to `100%` in the adornment. I had to copy the padding code [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js#L63-L74) to make sure the height of the adornment is the same as the height of the `OutlinedInput`:

```
<TextField
  placeholder="With normal TextField"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      paddingLeft: 0
    }
  }}
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment
        sx={{
          padding: "27.5px 14px",
          backgroundColor: (theme) => theme.palette.divider,
          borderTopLeftRadius: (theme) =>
            theme.shape.borderRadius + "px",
          borderBottomLeftRadius: (theme) =>
            theme.shape.borderRadius + "px"
        }}
        position="start"
      >
        kg
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
```

### Live Demo

**V5**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: How can i achive it material ui 4

Comment: @SmackAlpha I just added the v4 Codesandbox.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Thanks, here's also a quick sandbox I made (MUI v5) that could help future visitors: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-https-umjiv6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can do this in simple way .Try this one

```
InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <div style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center', backgroundColor:'#E1E8EB',height:55,width:50,marginLeft:-13,border:'0px solid green',marginRight:5}}>
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    
                    <VpnKeyIcon style={{marginLeft:10}} />
                    
                  </InputAdornment>
                  </div>
                )
              }}
```